# Mac OS X 10.11 brew install boost-python end up in dead loop

Tags: macos, boost, homebrew, boost-python, caffe

I am trying to get caffe, which needs `boost-python` installed on my Mac.

When I installed `boost-python` with `brew install --build-from-source --fresh -vd boost-python`, it ended in dead loops and never finished. I could only interrupt with Ctrl+C.

Here are the error messages. The following message just loop endlessly...

```
<scratch space>:6:1: note: expanded from here
boost_static_assert_typedef_508
^
In file included from libs/coroutine/src/posix/stack_traits.cpp:22:
In file included from ./boost/thread.hpp:24:
In file included from ./boost/thread/future.hpp:40:
In file included from ./boost/thread/csbl/memory/unique_ptr.hpp:16:
./boost/move/unique_ptr.hpp:554:7: warning: unused typedef     'boost_static_assert_typedef_555' [-Wunused-local-typedef]
      BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(( !::boost::move_upmu::missing_virtual_destructor
  ^
./boost/static_assert.hpp:170:16: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT'
               BOOST_JOIN(boost_static_assert_typedef_, __LINE__) BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_UNUSED_ATTRIBUTE
               ^
./boost/config/suffix.hpp:544:28: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_JOIN'
#define BOOST_JOIN( X, Y ) BOOST_DO_JOIN( X, Y )
                           ^
./boost/config/suffix.hpp:545:31: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_DO_JOIN'
#define BOOST_DO_JOIN( X, Y ) BOOST_DO_JOIN2(X,Y)
                              ^
./boost/config/suffix.hpp:546:32: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_DO_JOIN2'
#define BOOST_DO_JOIN2( X, Y ) X##Y
                               ^
```

I have tried using other versions of boost-python but there's no luck...

I'm new to OS X and don't know what to do. Googling yielded some similar cases while people are actually using boost, but it I couldn't find any fixes for installing boost... Any help is greatly appreciated.

OS condition:

- Just formatted hard drive and reinstalled Mac OS X
- installed Xcode, homebrew
- installed pyenv with homebrew
- installed anaconda with pyenv
- installed hdf5, opencv with homebrew
- edited formulas for other caffe dependencies with:

.

```
def install
  # ADD THE FOLLOWING:
  ENV.append "CXXFLAGS", "-stdlib=libstdc++"
  ENV.append "CFLAGS", "-stdlib=libstdc++"
  ENV.append "LDFLAGS", "-stdlib=libstdc++ -lstdc++"
  # The following is necessary because libtool likes to strip LDFLAGS:
  ENV["CXX"] = "/usr/bin/clang++ -stdlib=libstdc++"
```

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Comment: I kind of solved this- the issue is with the -Python flag. I ended up switching to macports and not using any flags. I'm not all sure why this works. Also for some reason Xcode 7.3 doesn't work with Cuda so you have to downgrade.

Comment: That worked - I can compile caffe now, thanks! However I can't compile pycaffe because boost-python can only be installed with brew (port doesn't have that package. and actually `-python` is not a flag, it's part of the package name (boost for python))

Comment: Also... Strangely, now that I've installed boost with macports, I retried with `brew update` then `brew install boost-python -vd` and it worked....... I have no idea why :S

Comment: Huh. I would check your ~/.bash_profile I bet macports updated it with your boost path

Comment: You are absolutely right - it added:`# MacPorts Installer addition on 2016-04-10_at_16:28:48: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.`